# subset() with grepl() using REGEX for filtering a dataframe in R

Tags: r, regex, subset, grepl

I am learning R and experimenting with subset() and grepl() with Regex for filtering a dataframe.  I have created a very small dataframe to play with:

```
x   y   z   w
1   10  a   k
2   12  b   l
3   14  c   m
4   16  d   n
5   18  e   o
```

My code is the following:

```
subset(df14, grepl('^c | [l - n]', c(df14$z , df14$w) ), grepl('[yz]', colnames(df14)) )
```

In my mind, the second argument should return the indices of the rows found by grepl() to match the pattern in the columns with names: 'z' or 'w'.  However, this is not what happens (returns an empty dataframe with columns y and z).

I would expect to return the rows 2,3,4 since column 'w' contains the letters l, m, n specified in the [l-n] regex pattern and the columns z and w since these names match the regex [yz] in the third argument of the subset().

(I suspect that it is looking for a match in the names of the columns rather the contents of the columns, which is what interests me.)

Obviously, I am not interested in the result per se.  This is an experiment to understand how the functions work.  So, what I am looking for is an explanation and a method to correct the specific code  -- not an alternative solution.

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your desired output though?  Also, if your columns contain single letters, there is no need in regex rather `==`/`%in%` or `match` should be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of problems.

One issue is the extra spaces in your patterns. Drop them or use the free-spacing modifier `(?x)` with `perl = TRUE`. Either way, you have to get rid of the spaces in the character class.  `[l-n]` matches "m" and `[l - n]` does not, even with `(?x)`.  You can read more about the free-spacing modifier and its impact inside and outside character classes [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html).

Another issues is that in your first `grepl`, you're searching within a vector (character vector? we can't tell from the example) of length 10. What would a TRUE in the 6th position mean for a 5 row data.frame? It doesn't make sense to return the 6th row of a 5 row data frame. Instead, you can see if your pattern is found for column "w" or (`|`) column "z".  Look within each column, not a concatenation of columns.

Another issue is in your second `grepl`, "w" is not a match for `[yz]`.  If you want to select the columns with a name containing a "w" or a "z", one way would be with `[wz]`:

There is no need for the `^` anchor since all your strings contain a single character, but I'll leave it in anyway:

```
subset(df14, 
       subset = grepl('^c|[l-n]', df14$z) | 
           grepl('^c|[l-n]', df14$w),
       select = grepl('[wz]', colnames(df14)))
#  z w
#2 b l
#3 c m
#4 d n
```

Or with the free-spacing mode modifier and a different pattern (`[wz]` vs `w|z`) for the second `grepl`:

```
subset(df14, 
       subset = grepl('(?x)^c | [l-n]', df14$z, perl = TRUE) | 
           grepl('(?x)^c | [l-n]', df14$w, perl = TRUE),
       select = grepl('w|z', colnames(df14)))
#  z w
#2 b l
#3 c m
#4 d n
```

Answer (score 0):

The `'^c | [l - n]'` search expression can't find anything in those columns. Also, a more intuitive approach is use `[ , ]` to do this type of subsetting. See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html.

Comment: But does not w contains the letters l, m, n?